# × TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined but can console.log the key holding the array - ReactJS with hooks

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, function

Apologies but i'm bashing my head off a wall with this and none of the other examples i've seen on here have helped. I am trying to map the contents of the array held in the `data` key of a JSON object which is fetched from the weatherbit API. I'm doing this so that I can access the array properties (including the nested `weather` object) for a weather app I am trying to build in modern React (I am using hooks). I've screenshotted the JSON so you can see the API structure.

[image: Uncollapsed]

[image: Collapsed]

I can see the array in the inspection window of the browser when I `console.log(currentWeather.data)`. Why can I not map this given that my map is pointing to the data key/attribute of the `currentWeather` object? I keep receiving "cannot read property 'map' of undefined'.

I have a component called `CurrentWeatherList` which is performing the mapping and then passing the mapped array down as props:

```
import CurrentWeather from './CurrentWeather';

function CurrentWeatherList({currentWeather}){

    // return nothing if there is no current weather object, otherwise...
    if (!currentWeather) return null;

    console.log(currentWeather);
    console.log(currentWeather.data);


    // Map the currentWeather
    const displayCurrentWeather = currentWeather.data.map(weather => {
        return <CurrentWeather
                weather={weather}/>
    })

    return(
        <>
        {displayCurrentWeather}
        </>
    )
}



export default CurrentWeatherList;
```

Edited:

My container, `CurrentWeatherContainer` which is performing the fetch from the API is below. I'm using a key but this is for a practice project from a free account - I can omit if i'm violating any policy:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import CurrentWeatherList from "../components/CurrentWeatherList";
import LocationAsCityForm from "../components/LocationAsCityForm";

function CurrentWeatherContainer(){

    // Sets state for the current weather object
    // also sets state for the location input by the user from LocationAsCityForm
    const [currentWeather, setCurrentWeather] = useState([]);
    const [location, setLocation] = useState("");

    
    // handles the location submitted by the "as city" form
    // invokes the fetch passing the location to getCurrentWeatherAsCity

    const handleLocationAsCitySubmit = (location) => {
        getCurrentWeatherAsCity(location);
    }

    // This is the fetch which provides currentWeather from the API using the form location input by user
    
    const getCurrentWeatherAsCity = (location) => {
    const url = "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?city="+location+"&key=42f951c1eea94e33a68cd790a1f613fb"

    console.log("Url: " + url);
    
    fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            setCurrentWeather(data);
        })

    }

    // Format the user input to the form
    
    const formatInput = (userInput) => {
        const lowerCase = userInput.toLowerCase();
        const formattedString = lowerCase;
        return formattedString;
    }


    return(
        <>
        This is the CurrentWeatherContainer
        <LocationAsCityForm 
        handleLocationAsCitySubmit={handleLocationAsCitySubmit}
        location={location}
        setLocation={setLocation}
        formatInput={formatInput}
        />

        <CurrentWeatherList 
        location={location}
        currentWeather={currentWeather}
        />

        </>
    )


}


export default CurrentWeatherContainer;
```

And finally the code for the  `LocationAsCityForm` component which takes in the user inputted location to perform the fetch:

```
import { Form, Input } from 'semantic-ui-react'

function LocationAsCityForm({handleLocationAsCitySubmit, location, setLocation, formatInput}) {

    const handleInput = (event) => {
        const formattedInput = formatInput(event.target.value);
        setLocation(formattedInput);
    }

    const submitIngredients = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        handleLocationAsCitySubmit(location);
    
    }
    return (
        <> 
    
            <Form className="form-box" onSubmit={submitIngredients}>
                             
                    <Form.Field>
                    <label>Enter your location</label>
                    <Input action='Search' placeholder='e.g. Edinburgh, UK...' onChange={handleInput}/>
                    </Form.Field>              
           </Form>

        </>
    );
}

export default LocationAsCityForm;
```

Comment: I don't see any problem here based on the limited amount of code shown. Please provide a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: Could I provide the GitHub link? It is not a particularly large project. Only several components and a container at this stage.

Comment: It's better to put it in the question itself. SO is about curating a resource for future visitors, and links will go stale over time. The idea is a simple, reproducible example that serves to create a clear problem-solution resource in the thread. if the problem is buried behind a dead link, that's not a helpful post.

Comment: currentWeather.data is an object no ? the array is currentWeather.data.data ?

Comment: No, it's an array with one object in it. Or appears to be.

Comment: Oh ok thanks @ggorlen my bad

Comment: @ggorlen it has the "data" key and the "count" key but the "count" key is not required for extraction (shown at the bottom of the image). I'm unable to alter the image size for readability. However, I will update my question to show the container as that is where the state is held from the fetched API data.

Comment: All of that is fine and well and thanks for editing, but keep in mind that based on what's shown, there should be no problem. So you've accidentally omitted some critical information that's actually causing the problem. You mention you're fetching data .... that might be worth including.

Comment: @ggorlen I have updated my question to include the 2 components and main container I have written so far. Please let me know if this is too much detail - i'm trying to be conscious of providing a manageable amount of information for users to help me with my problem without overloading. Thank you.

Comment: do you try to directly map in your return ? why do you save your map in const displayCurrentWeather ? @loco

Comment: @Daphaz yes the map is directly returning weather as props to the CurrentWeather component. I have done this in other similar projects before - i'm a beginner with React. But i'm open to doing it differently. This type of mapping has worked for me in the past

Comment: I say this because I think that maybe the data is not yet there so you can test before
like 
return (
 <>
  {
   currentWeather.data && currentWeather.data.map(.....)
  }
</>
)

Comment: Remember that console.log does _not_ run synchronously, and is not a reliable method of logging the state of a variable "right now". Set a breakpoint in the browser and inspect the variable's value instead. Or, copy the var content in a way that is synchronous (e.g `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(..))`) but if you can set breakpoints, that's by far a better way to gain insight.

Comment: @Daphaz if the data isn't there wouldn't I have issues console logging it? the map is invoked once the data has been fetched and passed down. I am only fetching from a single end point so I don't see why i'd need to account for any synchronous issues.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't know if it helps but within CurrentWeatherList I am able to return {currentWeather.count} and see the value of "1" render in the browser on my view - would that indicate that the data has successfully loaded? It will let me access the data within the key of "count" but not "data" i.e the array. I am baffled. I'm not able to make sense of what i've tried using the dev tool breakpoints.